# Black out application when shared in teams

Tags: microsoft-teams, microsoft-information-protection

MS Office has a great feature I would like to implement in my application, but don't know where to start...

When an AIP classified document is opened in an Office application and shared in a Teams session, the windows appears as a black rectangle.

Tried to search Microsoft MIP & Teams SDK, but didn't it. Does anyone of you know how to tackle this issue?

Comment: Are you developing any Teams app? You want to Black out the custom Teams app?

Comment: We have a .Net application which is  displaying confidential data that should not be shared over Teams. That’s why I would like to implement the blackout functionality

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be any Teams SDK method available to Black out application when shared in teams